How to use servlets in jakarta ee 9, jsf 3.0?
I am working on refactoring a project to microservices architecture. The system is kinda old (written in jakarta ee 9, jsf 3.0). I am trying to navigate from a page to another. The request should be handled by a servlet before sending the result to the page i am navigating to. The problem is that the data that should come from the servlet isn't displayed in the destination page. Since I am familiar to spring boot, I tried to apply the same logic of servlets but it doesn't seem to work the same. Could you help me ?
I am trying to navigate from /index.xhtml to /result.xhtml :
<h:link value="Place an order" outcome="result" />

result points to /result.xhtml which is :
<h:body>
   <ui:include src="/header.xhtml" />

   <h2>Order your food</h2>

   <h:form>
      <ul>
         <c:forEach items="#{menuItems}" var="menuItem">
            <li>#{menuItem}
               <h:inputText id="item_#{menuItem.id}" />
            </li>
         </c:forEach>
      </ul>

      <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{order.placeOrder}" />
   </h:form>

"menuItems" should come from the servlet :
@WebServlet(name = "result",urlPatterns = "/result")
public class OrderServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        MenuDao menuDao = MenuDaoFactory.getMenuDao();

        List<MenuItem> menuItems = menuDao.getFullMenu();

        request.setAttribute("menuItems", menuItems);

        ServletContext context = getServletContext();

        RequestDispatcher dispatch = context.getRequestDispatcher("/result.xhtml");
        dispatch.forward(request, response);

    }
}

When changing urlPatterns="/result" to "/result.xhtml" i get an error of a looping request.

JSF doesn't use servlets.

Indeed. Just use a managed bean. See abovelinked duplicate for a kickoff example.
